# ClickOnce - Installation folder Setup on the server side

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am traying to publish an application via ftp, using visual studio 2015 and Net Framework 4.5.2

I have a local ftp in a lan web.

But do i need to create a iis website for the **Installation folder Setup**? if i neeed to do that how to configure it to point to the ftp?

I just want to use only the ftp is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's possible.

When you publish an application by using ClickOnce, the `Publish Location` property specifies the location where the application files and manifest are put. This can be a file path or the path to an FTP server.

You can specify the `Publish Location` property on the `Publish` page of the `Project Designer`, or by using the Publish Wizard. For more information, see [How to: Publish a ClickOnce Application using the Publish Wizard.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-publish-a-clickonce-application-using-the-publish-wizard?view=vs-2022)

## To specify a publishing location

1. With a project selected in `Solution Explorer`, on the `Project` menu, click `Properties`.
2. Click the `Publish` tab.
3. In the `Publish Location` field, enter the publishing location by using one of the following formats:

- To publish to a file share or disk path, enter the path by using either a UNC path (\Server\ApplicationName) or a file path (C:\Deploy\ApplicationName).
- To publish to an FTP server, enter the path using the format ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/.

Note that text must be present in the `Publishing Location` box in order for the Browse (...) button to work.